# how to pass dynamic URL to curl in php - getting error 1

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm trying to pass a $url to curl using a function.
the URL is built with a variable in it in the following method:

```
a.php // main page, include (a.php, b.php)
b.php // dynamic string function
c.php // curl function
```

I build a dynamic string successfully using sessions data // $_SESSION["input"]
myDynamicstringfunction set a string by multiple sessions input values.

```
$dval = myDynamicstringfunction();
echo $dval;
// render correctly to: "-e5 -g6 -g7"
```

the $dval value is a string that resolve as expected. the $url is:

```
$url = "https://someurl.com/a/b?dc=-cv1.5 -a1 -b2 -c3 -d4 $dval";
```

The $url is render correctly with the

```
echo $url;
$url = "https://someurl.com/a/b?dc=-cv1.5 -a1 -b2 -c3 -d4 -e5 -g6 -g7";
```

I pass the $url to the curl function using:

```
$r = mycUrlfunction($url);
```

The curl function I use:

```
function singleRequest($url){
$ch = curl_init();
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$curly = curl_exec($ch);
if ($curly == FALSE){
    die("cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch));
}

$result = json_decode($curly, true);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
return ($result);
}
```

The above get me an error (curl 1) - CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL (1)

I have tried many things to get the $url to work with no success.
if I set the $url value manually without the $dval variable like this:

```
$url = "https://someurl.com/a/b?dc=-cv1.5 -a1 -b2 -c3 -d4 -e5 -g6 -g7";
```

The code works just fine and I get the correct results from the API call.
I tried using different quotes, {}, [], encoding to ASCII, vprintf(), and other solutions with no success.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If the URL is generated correctly, what's the difference between the correct URL generated, and the manually set URL?

Comment: I think you just miss `{}` in `$url = "https://someurl.com/a/b?dc=-cv1.5 -a1 -b2 -c3 -d4 {$dval}";`

Comment: @NicoHaase the problem is that the curl function singleRequest($url) does not return the array when I use  "https://someurl.com/a/b?dc=-cv1.5 -a1 -b2 -c3 -d4 $dval";

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? What's the difference between the two values of `$url` in the working and the non-working case?

Comment: @NicoHaase the $url is generated correctly and there is no difference between the generated url and the manual url. I cannot seem to understand why the URL with the vibrable doesn't resolve when its been passed to curl, although that I tested to see if the curl return the $URL it gets correctly (and it does).

Comment: @ikhvjs thanks for the suggestion. i already tried it among other things...

Comment: Just to be sure: did you dump the URLs in `singleRequest` to see whether there is exactly **no** difference between the two URLs, as in: they are bit-by-bit exactly equal? There are no spaces, hidden characters, or anything else interfering?

Comment: @NicoHaase I used echo to compare the strings. when using var_dump as you suggested I get a hidden value "string(204)" at the beginning of the URL 'string(204) "https://someurl.com/a/b?dc=-cv1.5 -a1 -b2 -c3 -d4 -e5 -g6 -g7";` I'm not sure where is the 'string(204) ' comes from. any idea what can trigger this?

Comment: Sounds like you should start debugging your code. If `var_dump` does not help, start using XDebug to step through the execution of your code

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with constructing the dynamic variable `$dynamicstring` of the URL
initially used

```
$dynamicstring= "-a" . $_SESSION["a"]." -b".$_SESSION['b']." -c".$_SESSION['c']." -d".$_SESSION['d']."<br>";
```

this have a few problems

1. when using echo it render the expected output correctly
2. it have a `"<br>"` at the end
3. it have the wrong structure

the correct way to construct the `$dynamicstring` is to use {}

```
$dynamicstring= "-a{$_SESSION["a"]} -b{$_SESSION['b']} -c{$_SESSION['c']} -d{$_SESSION['d']}";
```